# Finding the closest point to a sets of discrete points

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom

In a paper I am reviewing, the authors define the following problem and construct an algorithm. They give no further references and I suspect it has appeared somewhere in the literature before.

Let $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ be sets of points in a space with a metric $d$. Define the distance to a set as 
    $$\operatorname{dist}(x, P_i) = \min\{ d(x,p) \,|\, x \in P_i\}.$$
The problem is to compute
    $$\min_x \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{dist}(x, P_i).$$
What is the name of this problem? Has it been discussed in the literature? What if $d(x,P_i) = ||x - P_i||_2?$

Comment: I don't know of any references to that specific formula, but wouldn't this be covered under optimization/minimization problems?

Comment: It seems like a generalized 1-median problem.

Comment: The 1-median problem would be to minimize sum_i sum_{p in P_i} d(x, p), right? Has the generalized version appeared anywhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Of course it inherits all of the hardness of the 1-median since all the sets can be singletons. It should also admit the 2-approximation that comes from choosing one of the input points as the center.

Answer (score 4):

It is called p-Median and is known to be NP-hard.
Refer to the following paper for more info:

> O. Kariv and S. Hakimi, “[An Algorithmic Approach to Network Location
>   Problems. II: The p-MEDIANS](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2100911),” *SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics*,
>   vol. 37, no. 3, pp. 539–560, December 1979.

Comment: That seems to be about the special case where the sets $P_i$ consist of every one of the $\binom{n}{p}$ subsets of $p$ points of the input, and the NP-hardness result in that paper requires $p$ to be non-constant. So this doesn't appear to say much about the hardness of the problem asked here in which the $P_i$ are specified, because expanding out all of the $p$-subsets into an explicit list of sets is not a polynomial-time reduction.